# WooCommerce block product hooks

Tags: woocommerce, product

Is there a hook we can use to interact with products in WooCommerce block?

https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-blocks/

For example if I use woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item, this does not get called.